# Record Method calls and Property access in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, hook

I wanted to find out if there is any way to record all method calls(with arguments) and property access in Javascript.
For example:
1- I want to be informed when a canvas is being created by `document.createElement("CANVAS");` 
2- I need to be informed when a script is trying to access `navigator.plugins` or `window.screen`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add hooks to functions, for example like this:

```js
let calls = (function(){
    let calls = 0;
    let fun = document.createElement;
    document.createElement = function(){
      calls++;
      return fun.apply(document, arguments);
    }
    return ()=>calls;
})();
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(200, 0, 0)';
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
console.log("calls of document.createElement:", calls());
```

Small notice: don't try in a SO snippet to do a `console.log` from a hooked `document.createElement` as `console.log` itself is hooked by the snipped engine to build elements...

Another approach is to set proxies for object:

```js
    Object.defineProperty(window, "navigator", {
     value: new Proxy(window.navigator, {
      get: function(target, name) {
       console.log("navigator property", name, "is read")
       return target[name];
      }
     })
    });
    console.log("plugins:", window.navigator.plugins);
```

Comment: Dear Denys, I wanted to know how to define a proxy for windows.navigator.plugins exclusively, windows.navigator is too general, For example I want to define a proxy for navigator.useragent but I get error for invalid Javascript